# How can I parse this xml returned from a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have the following xml return from my url:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<categories>
  <category>
    <catid>17</catid>
    <name>Collage</name>
    <parent></parent>
  </category>
  <category>
    <catid>15</catid>
    <name>Letter Mats</name>
    <parent></parent>
  </category>
  <category>
    <catid>182</catid>
    <name>Single Opening</name>
    <parent></parent>
  </category>
</categories>
```

And my javascript code, I have:

```
var matte_select_options = new Array();
function matte_designs_populate_types()
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "myurl/system/components/catsxml/3",
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function(xml) {
        designs = xml.getElementsByTagName("categories")[0].childNodes;
        var output = [];
        alert(designs.length);
        for (i = 0; i < designs.length; i++)
        {
          var catid = designs[i].getAttribute("catid");
          var name = designs[i].getAttribute("name");
          output.push('<option value="'+ catid +'">'+ name +'</option>');
          matte_select_options[catid] = name;
        }

        $('#matte_designs').html(output.join(''));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

For some reason, the alert is giving me 7 and I am not sure why. The main issue though, is the select is not populating because catid and name are not even being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the returned XML into a jQuery object, then use jQuery's DOM traversal functions as you normally would. Try this:

```
success: function(xml) {
    var output = [];
    $('category', xml).each(function(i, el) {
        var catid = $("catid", this).text();
        var name = $("name", this).text();
        output.push($('<option />', { value: catid, text: name }));
        matte_select_options[catid] = name;
    });
    $('#matte_designs').html(output);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/myL6C/1)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan wouldn't you recommend the use of [jquery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)?

Answer (score 1):

In your xml example : `catid` and `name` are not atrributes. They are nodes, and the information is contained in their content.

If you are using `jQuery`, you should be able to parse the xml using `jQuery` selectors and manipulators :

```
success: function(xml) {
    var designs = $(xml).find('category');
    var output = [];

    designs.each(function(){
        var catid = $(this).find('catid').text();
        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
        output.push('<option value="'+ catid +'">'+ name +'</option>');
        matte_select_options[catid] = name;
    });

    $('#matte_designs').html(output.join(''));
  }
```